# crtls Valid heap pointer(block) in my header class

Tags: c++11

I tried to increase a pointer size by creating another pointer and then copying it to the original pointer but firstly it only has prints the address of the memory stored in it and then it crashes with a debug assertion fail.

```
int sumArray(int* arr, unsigned r) {

    r++;
    int *secArr = new int[r];
    for (int i = 0; i<r - 1; i++)   
    {
        secArr[i] = arr[i];  
    }

    secArr[r - 1] = sum % r;

    delete[] arr;

    arr = new int[r];


    for (size_t i = 0; i < r - 1; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = secArr[i];
    }
    delete[] secArr;        

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you know about the `std::copy_n` function? Works on iterators, but `int*` is a type of iterator.

Comment: yeah but copy_n is deprecated and it doesnt allow me to use it

Comment: Deprecated? Not at all. It's been part of C++11, C++14 and now is part of C++17, and it looks like it will be in C++20 next year.

Answer (score 1):

C++ uses pass-by-value, unless you explicitly use references. Now `int* arr` is a pointer, and that pointer is passed by value here. That means you get a copy of the pointer, but not of the pointed-to elements. So you can update `arr[0]` but not `arr` itself.

Having said that, don't use pointers like this. Use `std::vector<int>& arr`.

Comment: @shinigamidorobu: Well, the usual advice would be to wrap up the pointer in a class that takes care of ownership. However, that is pointless here, because you'd end up duplicating the functionality of `std::vector`. That already wraps up a pointer to a contiguous array, making it possible to pass that array by reference.

Comment: If you insist on using raw pointers, you'll have to use reference-to-pointer or pointer-to-pointer, whichever is less confusing to you. Or you can return updated pointer as function result.